# Create a new table with columns with case statements and max function

Tags: sql, teradata

I have some problems in creating a new table from an old one with new columns defined by case statements.

I need to add to a new table three columns, where I compute the maximum based on different conditions. Specifically,

1. if time is between 1 and 3, I define a variable max_var_1_3 as max((-1)*var),
2. if time is between 1 and 6, I define a variable max_var_1_6 as max((-1)*var),
3. if time is between 1 and 12, I define a variable max_var_1_12 as max((-1)*var),

The max function needs to take the maximum value of the variable var in the window between 1 and 3, 1 and 6, 1 and 12 respectively.

I wrote this

```
create table new as(
select t1.*,
  (case when time between 1 and 3 then MAX((-1)*var) 
 else var
end) as max_var_1_3,
  (case when time between 1 and 6 then MAX((-1)*var) 
 else var
end) as max_var_1_6,
  (case when time between 1 and 12 then MAX((-1)*var) 
 else var
end) as max_var_1_12
from old_table t1
group by time
) with data primary index time
```

but unfortunately it is not working. The old_table has already some columns, and I would like to import all of them and then compare the old table with the new one. I got an error that says that should be something between ) and ',', but I cannot understand what. I am using Teradata SQL. 
Could you please help me?

Many thanks

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. What does "not working" mean? Please read [ask].

Comment: Sample data, desired results, and an appropriate database tag would all help.

Comment: I got an error which says that should be something between ) and ','. Unfortunately, I cannot share any sample data. I asked to understand if I am doing something not correctly. I tried to explain as best as I can. As results, I would like to build a table using case when statements and max (aggregation) functions to compute the new columns in the new table. Thanks for your help

Comment: What is the exact error message? Just copy&paste, pls. And which ```)``` and ```,``` are those with the problem? I cannot find any directly besides the other..

Comment: Syntax error: expected something between ')' and ','. After group by time and ). There is no comma, however, in the code. But I think the problem is in the case when and max

Comment: I don't now how your SQL dialect handles this, but what do you expect from selecting ```var``` from a group. It is not grouped by ```var``` and you do not use it in an aggregate function (in all the ```else``` clauses)

Comment: Just try to add a ```;``` to the end of the command. Is it still the same error? Is it perhaps a missing ```;``` and this statement is called inside a script?

Comment: Yes, I already tried to add ; but nothing has changed. Is it correct to define the new columns as I did by using case when statements? Because I was thinking that I could do something different maybe using MAX(case when... ) as. However, even in this way, it does not work

Comment: Using ```MAX()``` outside of the ```CASE``` would at least give you a deterministic result.. But I am not really sure, if this is what you want at all. Do you want to have all data from your old table and add three columns with constant values and put this in a new table (this is what I think by reading the text)? This is not what your ```SELECT``` will generate. I cannot help you with the ```CREATE TABLE AS``` (since I don't know that much about your SQL dialect), but perhaps I can fix the query (if I understood your text correctly)

Comment: Thanks Islingre. Yes, you understood well. I have a table (old table) that contains some columns and values. I would like to create a new table just to add these three new columns. But I am not sure on how to create a table with case when statements and max function, distinguish var based on the time (1-3,1-6 and 1-12). I thought it was correct to use create table as because I found it on a SQL book, but something does not work.

Comment: the variable var is from the old table, I forgot to say

Comment: you are selecting all the columns and in group by you have given only one column , I think you are using teradata and this will not work in teradata.

Comment: Create a view instead, will always have up to date contents. A table will end up with inconcistent data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you have `GROUP BY time` in your query while trying to return all the other values with your `SELECT t1.*`.  To make your query work as-is, you'd need to add each column from `t1.*` to your `GROUP BY` clause.

If you want to find the `MAX` value within the different `time` ranges AND also return all the rows, then you can use a window function.  Something like this:

```sql
CREATE TABLE new AS (
  SELECT 
    t1.*,
    CASE 
      WHEN t1.time BETWEEN 1 AND 3 THEN (
        MAX(CASE WHEN t1.time BETWEEN 1 AND 3 THEN (-1 * t1.var) ELSE NULL END) OVER()
      ) 
      ELSE t1.var 
    END AS max_var_1_3,
    CASE 
      WHEN t1.time BETWEEN 1 AND 6 THEN (
        MAX(CASE WHEN t1.time BETWEEN 1 AND 6 THEN (-1 * t1.var) ELSE NULL END) OVER()
      ) 
      ELSE t1.var 
    END AS max_var_1_6,
    CASE 
      WHEN t1.time BETWEEN 1 AND 12 THEN (
        MAX(CASE WHEN t1.time BETWEEN 1 AND 12 THEN (-1 * t1.var) ELSE NULL END) OVER()
      ) 
      ELSE t1.var 
    END AS max_var_1_12,
  FROM old_table t1
) WITH DATA PRIMARY INDEX (time)
;
```

Here's the logic:

- check if a row falls in the range
- if it does, return the desired `MAX` value for rows in that range
- otherwise, just return that given row's default value (`var`)
- return all rows along with the three new columns

If you have performance issues, you could also move the `max_var` calculations to a `CTE`, since they only need to be calculated once.  Also to avoid confusion, you may want to explicitly specify the values in your `SELECT` instead of using `t1.*`.

I don't have a TD system to test, but try it out and see if that works.

Comment: The CASEs can probably be simplified to `Coalesce(Max(CASE WHEN t1.time BETWEEN 1 AND 3 THEN -t1.var END) Over(), t1.var)`

Comment: Yep that seems to do the same thing.  And much cleaner too.

Answer (score 0):

I cannot help with the `CREATE TABLE AS`, but the query you want is this:

```sql
SELECT
    t.*,
    (SELECT MAX(-1 * var) FROM old_table WHERE time BETWEEN 1 AND 3) AS max_var_1_3,
    (SELECT MAX(-1 * var) FROM old_table WHERE time BETWEEN 1 AND 6) AS max_var_1_6,
    (SELECT MAX(-1 * var) FROM old_table WHERE time BETWEEN 1 AND 12) AS max_var_1_12
FROM old_table t;
```

Comment: Thank you for your answers.  I tried what you suggested and now it works.